# Qgis don't show geometries

Tags: qgis

When I select a object in a particular layer using qgis in order to get information about it, this object don't get resalted in red and in the qgis log a get the following error:

not found space object -1456845214

This issue occurs in some objects, but not all.

Comment: What type of storage is used for the layers that cause this problem?  Shapefile, PostGIS, Spatialite, or something else?  Are you using the identify tool?

Comment: additional to the above information please provide a screenshot of the error and your procedure how to cause the error. This might be a bug

Comment: Is it possible that you have not selected the layer and have the group selected....although i have never got that error code.